# Including 2 CAs in VirtualHost in Apache using httpd for https phone/server handshake

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I'm trying to load a server cert from godaddy so have xxxxxxx.crt, and bundle.crt, I've made a key/csr which we used to create the certs. I'm now trying to load another cert as the phone we're using has to handshake with our server, and then hopefully discover the manufacturer CA to provision securely.

My initial config looked like:

```
<VirtualHost ip.ip.ip.ip:443>
    JkMount /* worker1
    JkMount / worker1

    ServerAdmin email@email.co.uk
    ServerName identifier.server.domain.co.uk

    SSLEngine on
    SSLVerifyClient require

    SSLCertificateFile /path/path/XXXXXXXXxxxxxxx.crt
    SSLCACertificateFile /path/path/gd_bundle-g2.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/path/polycom.key

    SSLCertificateFile /path/path/Polycom_Root_CA.crt

    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    SSLOptions +ExportCertData

    ErrorLog logs/identifier.server.domain.co.uk-error_log
    CustomLog logs/identifier.server.domain.co.uk-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

When I comment out the Polycom cert, I can restart httpd with no errors, but trying to include this breaks the restart. Am I doing something incredibly stupid or do I have to concatenate the certs together?

Comment: You need to use a separate VirtualHost with a separate ServerName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my perceived issue by formatting the Polycom CA file as PEM instead of DER and made this the SSLCACertificateFile, and made the change;

```
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/path/gd_bundle-g2.crt
```

I now get a positive handshake from phone to server, and secure packets delivered.

Answer (score 0):

You can't load two certificates in a single virtualhost. It makes no sense

Rule is one x509 certificate per virtualhost.

If you want to add CA's in the chain that signed your cert just add them in a single SSLCACertificateFile.

Also, keep in mind that in 2.4 you can just skip the SSLCACertificateFile and add all certificate chain in SSLCertificateFile from leaf to root.

Comment: Thanks for this. I wasn't sure if you could do this, but had an inkling that this might be the case. I'm still unsure why my solution works based on your comments though ? :/